# How to display a warning message in page layout Based on new lead and existing lead

Tags: salesforce

I need to display an alert message to the user based on the below condition.

1. A new lead is created `(Status='New Prospect')` and `(Type = 'New')`
2. An Existing lead is modified and `(Type = 'New')` and `(Status = 'New Prospect' or 'untouched' or 'qualified')`

I have written a code to show a pop-up using vfpage and added in the page layout but unable to written code for whether it is a new lead or existing lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time Salesforce renders the page layout, you can't distinguish between a record that is "new" or "existing" - the record has to exist for the page to render.

You can check the `CreatedDate` field and apply a threshold (last 2 minutes, say) to decide what you want to call a new record.

The only way to actually intervene in a UI context at the creation of a new record or edit of an existing record is to implement Visualforce overrides for the New and Edit actions for this sObject type. Because that comes with a lot more effort and ongoing maintenance, as well as a poorer user experience, I don't really recommend it.